# Spek + Retrofit api test crashing

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, spek

I'm trying to test Retrofit api with Spek

It throws nullPointerException on the **on{...}** block

Associated stacktrace : https://pastebin.com/gy6dLtGg

Here’s my test class

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
class AccountCheckViewModelTest : Spek({

    include(RxSchedulersOverrideRule)

    val httpException = mock<HttpException> {
        on { code() }.thenReturn(400)
    }

    given(" account check view model") {
        var accountCheckRequest = mock<CheckExistingAccountRequest>()
        var accountCheckResponse = mock<CheckExistingAccountResponse>()
        var webService = mock<IAPICalls>()

        val accountCheckViewModel = spy(VMAccountCheck(webService))

        beforeEachTest {
            accountCheckRequest = mock<CheckExistingAccountRequest>() {
                on { email }.thenReturn("foo@mail")
            }

            accountCheckResponse = mock<CheckExistingAccountResponse>() {
                on { firstName }.thenReturn("foo")
                on { email }.thenReturn("foo@mail")
            }

            webService = mock<IAPICalls> {
                on { checkExistingAccount(accountCheckRequest) }.thenReturn(Flowable.just(accountCheckResponse))
            }
         }
        on("api success") {
            accountCheckViewModel.checkIfAccountExists(request = accountCheckRequest)

            it("should call live data with first name as foo") {
               verify(accountCheckViewModel, times(1)).updateLiveData(accountCheckResponse.firstName, accountCheckResponse.email, null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my RxSchedulersOverrideSpek class

```
 class RxSchedulersOverrideSpek : Spek({

    beforeGroup {
        RxJavaPlugins.onIoScheduler(Schedulers.trampoline())
        RxJavaPlugins.onComputationScheduler(Schedulers.trampoline())
        RxJavaPlugins.onNewThreadScheduler(Schedulers.trampoline())
    }
})
```

Comment: Please be aware that you missed `RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler( __ -> Schedulers.trampoline());` in your `beforeGroup`

Comment: Yes - NPE was because of missing RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler()

Answer (score 1):

You should use `memoized` to properly setup test values. The problem is that `accountCheckViewModel` was initialized in Spek's discovery phase, the `webService` mock that was passed to `accountCheckViewModel` was the value at that point (which you didn't mock any of its method). `beforeEachTest` is run during the execution phase, you've re-assigned `webService` here to the proper mock but `accountCheckViewModel` still holds the previous value.

```
given(" account check view model") {
  val accountCheckRequest by memoized {
    mock<CheckExistingAccountRequest>() {
      on { email }.thenReturn("foo@mail")
    }
  }
  val accountCheckResponse by memoized {
    mock<CheckExistingAccountResponse>() {
      on { firstName }.thenReturn("foo")
      on { email }.thenReturn("foo@mail")
    }
  }
  val webService by memoized {
    mock<IAPICalls> {
      on { checkExistingAccount(accountCheckRequest) }.thenReturn(Flowable.just(accountCheckResponse))
    }
  }

  val accountCheckViewModel by memoized {
    spy(VMAccountCheck(webService))
  }

  on("api success") {
    accountCheckViewModel.checkIfAccountExists(request = accountCheckRequest)

    it("should call live data with first name as foo") {
      verify(accountCheckViewModel, times(1)).updateLiveData(accountCheckResponse.firstName, accountCheckResponse.email, null)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using **RxJava2** with **RxAndroid** you should override the RxAndroid scheduler with `Schedulers.trampoline()`. This way all jobs that subscribes on trampoline() will be queued and executed one by one in the same thread.

```
RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
```

Your `RxSchedulersOverrideSpek.kt` should look like this:

```
object RxSchedulersOverrideSpek : Spek({

    beforeGroup {
        RxJavaPlugins.onIoScheduler(Schedulers.trampoline())
        RxJavaPlugins.onComputationScheduler(Schedulers.trampoline())
        RxJavaPlugins.onNewThreadScheduler(Schedulers.trampoline())
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
    }

    afterGroup {
        RxJavaPlugins.reset()
        RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
    }
})
```